# Automatically adjust text size in css depending on number of elements in grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is my css code :

```css
#my_div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 30px;
    grid-template-columns:1fr ;
    grid-gap: 0.2rem;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

This is a 30px high row where elements (all of them `JQuery UI` widgets) are lined up and flow horizontally.

When I have "too many" elements, they overflow. I would like them to reduce their size in order to fit in instead.

My workaround is as follows :

```css
#my_div label {
    font-size: 14px; /* Or whatever smaller value makes everything fit */
}

#my_div .ui-widget {
    font-size: 14px; /* Or whatever smaller value makes everything fit */
}
```

Is there a way to automatically adjust that size instead of having to do it manually ?

Comment: Simply, no there is not.

Comment: You can do it based on the window width but to do it based on the number of elements inside a div then you would need to write some complex javascript that would apply different font-size based on the number of children within a div

Answer (score 0):

Try to set font size in `%` like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #my_div label {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #my_div label {
        font-size: 50%;
      }
    }
```

and so on.